# converting negative float numbers to unsigned int

Tags: python, c, sockets, unsigned

Im trying to send a unsigned int data from a C server to a python client. The requirement is to send a negative float value to the client. currently the number is -5.700 and I have 2 problems.
1) I dont have a clue on how to retain the negativeness within uint32_t, im using the MSB as a flag bit to get around it. Is this fine? Does anyone has better suggestions?

2) I tried typecasting float 5.700 to uint32_t, i.e 
    `uint32_t fops = *(uint32_t*)(&float_var) //float_var is 5.700`
 And fops was assigned value 0x00..40b66666 which is being sent to the python client. now how do I retrieve  the float back from this value at the client?

update: As Mats suggested python struct unpacks -ve floats perfectly so there is no need to use a flag bit.

Comment: How are you doing the transfer and why is a uint32_t involved?

Comment: Client/server communications is typically over TCP (sometimes UDP). TCP is a sequence of bytes. To send a float, you must (somehow) convert your float to a sequence of bytes, transmit that sequence, and then reassemble the float. How you do so is up to you. (Though nowadays, there are several libraries for doing stuff like this, such as JSON, BSON, Protocol Buffers, MessagePack…) It would be good if you clarified what you're doing, and what protocol you're communicating with.

Comment: Also, are you *sure* about that cast being 0x00006666 / 26214? That'd more than likely correspond to a float of 3.6-ish * 10^-41. `0xc0b66666` or `0x40b66666` would be more likely.

Comment: The transfer is over tcp sockets but I follow a protocol which defines data in bit level hence the unsigned values. The server is written in c and I use tcp to send the unint data across and use python struct to unpack them.

Comment: Python struct has a float type, which _may_ work for you. Send the 4 bytes, call it a float on the python side and see what happens. If your two machines agree on what a float is, then it ought to work.

Comment: righto it is indeed 0x40b66666 for uint32_t. The cast was right but the variable instead of uint32_t was uint16_t. now its sorted. Cheers

Comment: what about the negativeness? any ideas how to receive it at the python end?

Comment: Well, it is inefficient, but how about sending an additional byte with two possible values, `0x0` and `0x1`, and then multiply by -1 at the Python's end if `0x1` was received?

Comment: have you tried reading it in python as a float? The uint32_t cast trick should put the right bits in fops and I assume you have a way to get fops to python. So it'll still look like a signed float on the python side.

Comment: How are you reading the bytes on the python side?

Comment: yes I can retrieve in python the right float value (5.7). but my problem is representing the negative. If I set the MSB for -ve numbers then what I read at the python client is incorrect since I need to check MSB before reading the float. What im thinking is to use a uint64_t where 32 bits represent float value and the rest 32 to notify -ve number as Lorenzo suggested. Then I can read 2 32bits at python client to get the correct number.

Comment: A single 32-bit number should work just fine. The floating point value is 32-bits long, and will fit in a 32-bit int [the cast is not 100% portable and technically undefined behaviour, but most compilers will do exactly what you expect]

Comment: Quoting: _//float_var is 5.700_ - you need to change your test to a negative number. -5.700 is 0xc0b66666 and that decodes properly on the python side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solutions are nearly always best: Make it a string, and transfer that, rather than a binary floating point representation. That way, you don't have to worry about differences in floating point representation or how to make Python "understand" your binary floating point value.

Edit1: However, if you transfer a 32-bit integer to a Python `data` object: I expect  `floatdata = struct.unpack("f", data)` should do the trick.

Edit2: Documentation for [`struct.unpack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) (and `struct.pack`)

Edit3: The `struct.unpack` does assume both machines use the same floating point format. This means the software isn't widely portable. But it should work ok on most commonly available platforms.

Comment: I agree this is better if the option is available. I understood the requirement to be to transfer a float in an unsigned 32 bit type in a way that could be decoded by Python.

Comment: I also agree that pack and unpack work great, so long as the client and server systems are homogeneous.

Comment: Yes, there is that. And if they are not, it's going to be HORRIBLY complicated to fix up - for example a machine with 36-bit `float` can't really send it to a machine with 32-bit floats. This is why using a text-based solution will be a better choice.

Comment: Well, you can can send it, if you are willing to put up with truncation (ie rounding). The only requirement I could see was the data delivered to the client had to fit in 32 bits.

Comment: It's not necessarily just truncation tho' - the 36 bits could be organized in a different way, using, say, 9 bits for exponent, etc.

Comment: My solution accounts for all that.

Comment: Yes, of course. It also means that the value has to be encoded into a 32-bit integer in a way that is understandable at the other side. Which may not be that trivial. And if this doesn't have to be be portable across many machines (after all, the two most common CPU's these days are x86 and ARM, both of which have IEEE-754 floating point).

Comment: I am only suggesting that given the requirements as stated, it is difficult to justify assuming homogeneity between the server and client. If the question is modified with "the floating point representation is exactly the same on both server and client machines", then of course my solution is overkill.

Comment: I take it you have in your possession some machines that you can test this on? Because I don't - unless I crack my Canon EOS 60D, perhaps that has a non-IEEE754 processor in it. Or the Sky HD+ box...

Comment: Given the requirement of "must be 32 bit", it could well be the server is running on some embedded processor communicating to a regular web client. The reasons for the requirement are not provided, otherwise the text solution you initially suggested would be my preference as well.

Comment: The requirement is for arm processor. As Mats suggested python struct unpacks -ve floats perfectly so there is no need to use a flag bit.

Answer (score 2):

The casting on the C side was just to take the 4 bytes representing a float and stick it into the fops variable for transfer. You transfer that to the python client somehow and its still the 4 bytes that represents the floating point number. You can use the struct module to take those 4 bytes and build a python float.

(edit) the hight bit is the problem. The uint32_t cast left off the high bit and as soon as that is set (0xc0b66666) as opposed to (0x40b66666), it works correctly in python. So, you could set MSB manually and it should work.

```
>>> import struct
>>> buf=struct.pack('i', 0xc0b66666) # this is like the C cast to uint32_t
>>> len(buf)
4
>>> struct.unpack('f', buf)[0]
-5.699999809265137
```

Comment: drats. i typed this up before realizing your signed-ed-ness was the only problem you were trying to solve.

Comment: did exactly this to get the positive float. this works perfectly

Comment: `struct unpack` will work just fine for negative numbers too. The sign on a 32-bit floating point number is encoded in the top bit, so using `0xc0b66666` should give the correct negative number. Of course, like I said in my answer below, this assumes that both sending and receiving machines have the same format for floating point. It's not guaranteed.

Comment: ...and setting MSB gets the negative. Geez, my C is rusty if I have to scratch my head over why your cast is clobbering high bit.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - indeed!

Comment: @tdelaney: I doubt it clobbers the high bit. I think the OP is just confused.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I concur. There must be some other bug for not being able to retrieve the negative value.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - I didn't notice it at first, but m2r0007's example shifts from -5.700 to 5.700. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C math functions [`frexpf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/frexp.html) to extract the exponent and mantissa of the `float`. Then, you can use [`ldexp()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ldexp) in Python to reconstitute the two.

The exponent is returned as a signed integer, and the mantissa a signed float in the interval `[.5, 1)` or `[-.5, -1)`, depending on sign of the `float`.

How you decide to encode and decode this information to and from a 32 bit unsigned number is up to you. But, assume you allow 16 bits for the mantissa. Then, you can multiply the mantissa by 2<sup>15</sup>, and then use the 16 bits to represent the rounded integer value of the result in [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The receiver could then take the 16 bits, convert into a signed integer, and divide by 2<sup>15</sup>.

The other 16 bits of your 32 bits could be used to represent the exponent in 2's complement as well.